# How to get any field in devops using logic apps?

Tags: azure, devops, azureportal

I am creating a logic app which will update the tags column in Azure DevOps with some value.

So how do I fetch that column into my logic apps so that I can update the values on that columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is easiest achieved using the code view. Firstly, Tags are not by default output as array, rather they are a string like:

```
"System_Tags": "MyTag1; MyTag2"
```

So, you'll also need to construct the array from that string using a split.

I have here a sample of how to initialize a variable using the result of a Get Work Item Details from Azure Devops:

```
"Initialize_variable": {
    "inputs": {
        "variables": [
            {
                "name": "Work item tags",
                "type": "array",
                "value": "@split(body('Get_work_item_details')?['fields']?['System_Tags'], '; ')"['System_Tags']}"
            }
        ]
    },
    "runAfter": {
        "Get_work_item_details": [
            "Succeeded"
        ]
    },
    "type": "InitializeVariable"
}
```

This will initialize your new variable with the tags of the queried work item.